# How to limit "Like" to 1 by fixing controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

We limited the user to 1 *Like* per comment in the model, but how can we do this in the controller because right now the user can still *Like* to infinity by keeping clicking the *Like* button repeatedly?

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]


  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.comment_likes.create(comment: @comment)
        @comment.increment!(:likes)
        @comment.create_activity :like
        flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

private
  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  def comment_params
    params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
  end
end
```

**This is how we know the models are working:**

In Console:

```
CommentLike.create!(user: User.first, comment: Comment.first)

User Load (0.3ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 
Comment Load (0.3ms) SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 
(0.1ms) begin transaction CommentLike Exists 
(0.2ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM "comment_likes" WHERE 
("comment_likes"."user_id" = 1 AND "comment_likes"."comment_id" = 1) 
LIMIT 1 

(0.1ms) rollback transaction ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User has already been taken
```

We continued the conversation from over here: [Limit user to 1 like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636998/limit-user-to-1-like/29654312#29654312) because the answerer and I couldn't figure out where the controller was going wrong.

Thank you for your expertise!

Comment: I agree with @FrederickCheung do not use `#create` also you realize you are setting `@comment` twice this is not the issue just a note. It is a lot easier to see now that only the pertinent information is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create` always returns a truthy value - it doesn't make sense to use it in an if statement like that.

you could do

```
comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
if comment_like.save
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Or altnernatively keep using `create` but check whether the object was actually saved (`persisted?` will tell you this)

Answer (score 2):

Add a validation on CommentLike.

`validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :comment_id`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `after_create` hook at CommentLike model to increment Comment.likes

inside your CommentLike model

```
...
after_create :increment_comment

...
private
def increment_comment
  comment.increment! :likes
  comment.create_activity :like
end
```

your `like` method now looks like this:

```
def like
  clike = current_user.comment_likes.where(comment: @comment).first
  if clike.nil?
    current_user.comment_likes.create!(comment: @comment)
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```